# Running Python scripts in Java class activity in Android Studio with Chaquopy

Tags: java, python-3.x, android-studio, face-recognition, chaquopy

I am trying to utilize some python scripts in an Android Application (Java).  I have configured Chaquopy following the instructions on their website.
https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/android.html

I have [found an example](https://web.archive.org/web/20200919052138/https://www.ericdecanini.com/2019/10/21/run-python-scripts-in-the-android-front-end-with-chaquopy/) of how to execute python scripts in a Kotlin application
but I am struggling to figure this out in Java.

If I understand correctly, the python script (.py) is stored in src/main/python and one can call this script from another activity and display the results in that same calling activity.

The example in Kotlin:

```
val python = Python.getInstance()
val pythonFile = python.getModule("helloworldscript")
val helloWorldString = pythonFile.callAttr("helloworld")
hello_textview.text = helloWorldString.toString()
```

I want to execute the following python script:

```
import os
import face_recognition
def cmd2():
    os.system("face_recognition ./event_faces/ ./event_images/")
```

This commandline tool from face_recognition allows the user to run facial recognition on a directory of images and compares them to a directory of known faces. The result is a printout of the files processed with any known or unknown faces being appended to the filename.
[image]

My Goal is to execute this python script and display the output in the activity (i.e textView)
Does anyone know if it is possible to use face_recognition in Android Studio with Chaquopy?
It is not listed so I am having some doubts https://chaquo.com/pypi-7.0/
Is it possible to make os. type calls in android application?

***ADDITIONALLY***
If anyone is aware of a way to perform facial recognition on a directory of images in Java without using python's face_recognition, please let me know.  I have attempted find a library like face_recognition for java but have not been successful.  The face_recognition library from Python has been working very well for me but now as I am trying to port my python scripts into a Android Studio project things are becoming a little tricky.

My code thus far:
Android Manifest

```
 <application
        android:name="com.chaquo.python.android.PyApplication"
```

app Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.chaquo.python'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29

    defaultConfig {
        python{
            staticProxy "bulk.py"
            pip{
                install "dlib"
                install "opencv-python"
                install "opencv-contrib-python"
                install "face_recognition"
                install "pillow"
                install "numpy"
                install "cv2"
                install "os"
            }
        }
        applicationId "com.projectdevelopment.faces"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
```

project gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://chaquo.com/maven" }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath "com.chaquo.python:gradle:8.0.0"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Activity executing the Python script

```
python.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //call python script and return output to this activity
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've heard from quite a few people who've used face_recognition successfully on Android. It's a pure-Python package, so it can be installed directly from PyPI and doesn't need to be in [Chaquopy's own package repository](https://chaquo.com/pypi-7.0/).

However, Chaquopy doesn't come with a Python executable, so running a command-line script with `os.system` is unlikely to work. Instead, you can just call the `face_recognition` Python API, which has many examples on [its own website](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition).

It looks like the closest equivalent to running the `face_recognition` script is to import [`face_recognition.face_recognition_cli`](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/blob/master/face_recognition/face_recognition_cli.py) and call the `main` function, possibly after setting up `sys.argv` with your command line.

Any text printed to standard output will go to [Logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html), which you can view in Android Studio. If you'd like to see it on the device screen as well, the easiest way is to adapt the [console app template](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy-console).

Comment: And to find your image files at runtime, use a path relative to `__file__`, as described [here](https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy/issues/144).

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have finally made significant progress.  I did migrate over to pycharm and am building the app in python entirely but your answer guided me in the right direction for utilising the face_recognition api.  (Lifesaver) thanks again.